# argparse validation in a python class

Tags: python, class, oop, pyinstaller, argparse

I'm trying an OOP approach to my Python code which eventually will be converted to an .EXE file created with PyInstaller. The idea is to pass a series of arguments from the user input (n to a program that eventually will go something like (`myprogram.exe -secureFolder C:/Users -thisisacsvfile.csv -countyCode 01069 -utmZone 15`).

I can initialize a class definition and pass the arguments like:

```
import argparse
import sys

class myprogram():
    def __init__(self, secureFolder, inputCsvFile, countyCode, utmZone):
        self.secureFolder = secureFolder
        self.inputCsvFile = inputCsvFile
        self.countyCode = countyCode
        self.utmZone = utmZone
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("secureFolder", help = "A directory where the files are located", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("inputCsvFile",  help="A CSV file containing the results for a particular county (e.g. 36107.csv)", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("countyCode", help = "The FIPS county code", type = str)
    parser.add_argument("utmZone", help = "The UTM zone code for that specific county (e.g. 18)", type = int)
```

However, I need to validate every user argument and that's the part where  I'm getting confused. In other words, I need to check if the `secureFolder` exists, if the `inputCsvFile` is indeed a CSV and contains some specific columns and other operations for the rest of the arguments. What I don't know exactly, where do I perform these operations? After the class definition?
Before the OOP approach, I was doing something like:

```
# Check if all the arguments were passed
undefined_arguments = [attr for attr in vars(args) if getattr(args, attr) is None]
if undefined_arguments:
    print("The following arguments were not defined:", undefined_arguments)
else:
    print("All arguments were defined.")

# 1a. Check inputCsvFile
if args.inputCsvFile is None:
    sys.exit("Please select an input CSV file to process (e.g. inputCsvFile.../myfile.csv) ")
else:
    if not os.path.isfile(args.inputCsvFile):
        sys.exit (f"File {args.inputCsvFile} doesn't appear to exists...please check if the file exists or if you have privileges to access it")
    else:
        grid_file_csv = args.inputCsvFile 
        print (f"{args.inputCsvFile} found...")

# 1b. Check if inputCsvFile is a CSV:
if not args.inputCsvFile.endswith('.csv'):
    raise ValueError("Invalid input file. Expected a CSV file.")
    sys.exit('No propper CSV file has been passed...')

# 2. Check if the FIPS code
if args.countyCode is None:
   sys.exit("Please specify a valid county code (e.g. -countyCode3607)")
             
# Check the UTM area code
if args.utmzone is None:
   sys.exit("Please specify a valid UTM zone area (e.g. -utmZone 16): ")

if args.utmZone is not None:
    val = args.utmZone 
    if val < 1 and val > 20:
        raise Exception('UTM zone area should be between 1 and 20')
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: You don't want potentially invalid data in your class instance. So, write a function that validates **all** of the input values. Call that with the user's input values and, if validation passes, then construct your *myprogram* instance

Comment: "...then construct your myprogram instance". Could you please detail that? Should 
I do something like:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = myprogram(args.secureFolder, args.inputCsvFile, args.countyCode, args.utmZone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is largely a question of style and preference. In my view, wherever possible, values needed to construct any class should be validated before the class is constructed - especially when it relies on user input.

So, get the command line arguments, validate them, then construct your class. Something like this:

```
import argparse
from sys import stderr
import os


class myprogram():
    def __init__(self, secureFolder, inputCsvFile, countyCode, utmZone):
        self.secureFolder = secureFolder
        self.inputCsvFile = inputCsvFile
        self.countyCode = countyCode
        self.utmZone = utmZone

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.secureFolder=}, {self.inputCsvFile=}, {self.countyCode=}, {self.utmZone=}'

    @staticmethod
    def validate(ns):
        if not os.path.isdir(ns.secureFolder):
            print(f'{ns.secureFolder} is not a valid folder', file=stderr)
            return None
        try:
            with open(ns.inputCsvFile) as _:
                ...
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Unable to open {ns.inputCsvFile} due to {e}', file=stderr)
            return None
        if ns.countyCode is None:
            print(f'{ns.countyCode} is an invalid county code', file=stderr)
            return None
        if (z := ns.utmZone) is None or z < 1 or z > 60:
            print(f'{z} is not a valid utmZone', file=stderr)
            return None
        return myprogram(ns.secureFolder, ns.inputCsvFile, ns.countyCode, ns.utmZone)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    cli = [
        ('-secureFolder', 'A directory where the files are located', str),
        ('-inputCsvFile', 'A CSV file containing the results for a particular county (e.g., 36107.csv)', str),
        ('-countyCode', 'The FIPS county code', str),
        ('-utmZone', 'The UTM zone code for that specific county (e.g., 18)', int)
    ]
    for c, h, t in cli:
        parser.add_argument(c, help=h, type=t)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if (mp := myprogram.validate(args)) is None:
        print('Unable to construct class instance')
    else:
        # at this point we have a valid myprogram class instance (mp)
        print(mp)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `argparse` library can do some validations for you, such as ensuring that the argument is required. For the rest, you can write small, concise validation functions:

```py
import argparse
import pathlib


class MyProgram:
    def __init__(self, secureFolder, inputCsvFile, countyCode, utmZone):
        self.secureFolder = secureFolder
        self.inputCsvFile = inputCsvFile
        self.countyCode = countyCode
        self.utmZone = utmZone


def validate_dir(value):
    path = pathlib.Path(value)
    if not path.is_dir():
        raise ValueError()
    return value


def validate_csv(value):
    path = pathlib.Path(value)
    if not path.exists():
        raise ValueError()
    if path.suffix != ".csv":
        raise ValueError()
    return value


def validate_utm_zone(value):
    value = int(value)
    if not (1 <= value <= 20):
        raise ValueError()
    return value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "-secureFolder",
        help="A directory where the files are located",
        type=validate_dir,
        required=True,
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-inputCsvFile",
        help="A CSV file containing the results for a particular county",
        type=validate_csv,
        required=True,
    )
    parser.add_argument("-countyCode", help="The FIPS county code", required=True)
    parser.add_argument(
        "-utmZone",
        help="The UTM zone code for that specific county (e.g. 18)",
        type=validate_utm_zone,
        required=True,
    )

    options = parser.parse_args()
    print(options)
    my_program = MyProgram(
        secureFolder=options.secureFolder,
        inputCsvFile=options.inputCsvFile,
        countyCode=options.countyCode,
        utmZone=options.utmZone,
    )
```

Here are some sample runs

```bash
# Happy path
$ python3  main.py -secureFolder ./myfolder -inputCsvFile input.csv -countyCode code-blah -utmZone 15 
Namespace(secureFolder='./myfolder', inputCsvFile='input.csv', countyCode='code-blah', utmZone=15)

# None of the arguments supplied
$ python3  main.py                                                                                   
usage: main.py [-h] -secureFolder SECUREFOLDER -inputCsvFile INPUTCSVFILE -countyCode COUNTYCODE -utmZone UTMZONE
main.py: error: the following arguments are required: -secureFolder, -inputCsvFile, -countyCode, -utmZone

# Directory /foobar does not exist
$ python3  main.py -secureFolder /foobar -inputCsvFile input.csv -countyCode code-blah -utmZone 15
usage: main.py [-h] -secureFolder SECUREFOLDER -inputCsvFile INPUTCSVFILE -countyCode COUNTYCODE -utmZone UTMZONE
main.py: error: argument -secureFolder: invalid validate_dir value: '/foobar'

# Invalid utmZone
$ python3  main.py -secureFolder ./myfolder -inputCsvFile input.csv -countyCode code-blah -utmZone foo
usage: main.py [-h] -secureFolder SECUREFOLDER -inputCsvFile INPUTCSVFILE -countyCode COUNTYCODE -utmZone UTMZONE
main.py: error: argument -utmZone: invalid validate_utm_zone value: 'foo'

# utmZone not in range
$ python3  main.py -secureFolder ./myfolder -inputCsvFile input.csv -countyCode code-blah -utmZone 21 
usage: main.py [-h] -secureFolder SECUREFOLDER -inputCsvFile INPUTCSVFILE -countyCode COUNTYCODE -utmZone UTMZONE
main.py: error: argument -utmZone: invalid validate_utm_zone value: '21'

# CSV file does not end with .csv
$ python3  main.py -secureFolder ./myfolder -inputCsvFile main.py -countyCode code-blah -utmZone 15
usage: main.py [-h] -secureFolder SECUREFOLDER -inputCsvFile INPUTCSVFILE -countyCode COUNTYCODE -utmZone UTMZONE
main.py: error: argument -inputCsvFile: invalid validate_csv value: 'main.py'

# csv does not exist
$ python3  main.py -secureFolder ./myfolder -inputCsvFile input.csv -countyCode code-blah -utmZone 15
usage: main.py [-h] -secureFolder SECUREFOLDER -inputCsvFile INPUTCSVFILE -countyCode COUNTYCODE -utmZone UTMZONE
main.py: error: argument -inputCsvFile: invalid validate_csv value: 'input.csv'

# Get help
$ python3 main.py -h                                                                                 
usage: main.py [-h] -secureFolder SECUREFOLDER -inputCsvFile INPUTCSVFILE -countyCode COUNTYCODE -utmZone UTMZONE

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -secureFolder SECUREFOLDER
                        A directory where the files are located
  -inputCsvFile INPUTCSVFILE
                        A CSV file containing the results for a particular county
  -countyCode COUNTYCODE
                        The FIPS county code
  -utmZone UTMZONE      The UTM zone code for that specific county (e.g. 18)
```